# In Flutter, how can I access a Google Docs document by it document ID?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-drive-api

**Background**

In Google Apps Script I can access an existing document in Google Drive by calling DocumentApp and using the openById method. For example:

```
var documentToAccess = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
```

Similarly, I can access a file in Google Drive bu calling DriveApp.getFileById. For example:

```
var fileToAccess = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
```

**Problem**

In Flutter, the googleapis dependency allows me to import several libraries including googleapis/drive/v3.dart, googleapis/docs/v1.dart, and googleapis/file/v1.dart which provide methods to access the attributes of files in Google Drive, but I can’t seem to find a method to actually get or open the file that I want to work on.

**Question**

In Flutter, how can I get a Google Docs document by its document ID so that I can then work on that document?

**googleapis Documentation and Other Attempts**

The [googleapis documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/) has some useful resources but despite attempting to implement these I can’t seem to get what I need. For example:

```
var fileToAccess = DriveApi().files.get('documentId’);
var fileToAccess = Document().documentId;
var fileToAccess = FilesResourceApi().get('documentId');
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the user is not signed in, so first, sign in the user.

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
  ],
);
```

To instantiate the client you would add something like:

```
 final client = MyClient(defaultHeaders: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${authentication.accessToken}'
    });
```

and then where you try to get the document :

```
DriveApi driveApi = DriveApi(client);
    var files = await driveApi.files
        .list(q: 'mimeType=\'application/vnd.google-apps.document\'');
```

Comment: Thank you! When I try this code I receive an error stating that _The getter 'client' isn't defined for the class '_reportingState'_. I imagine this is because client is undefined. When I review the documentation for the DriveApi class (https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.drive.v3/DriveApi-class.html) I see there is a DriveApi Client() constructor, but still don't understand how to create or define the client. Could you possibly help me understand how to do so?

Comment: I have added the client instantiation